# Monitoring SQS+Celery

Tags: celery, amazon-sqs, flower

Is where some flower analog which work with sqs+celery somehow? I found out that in current celery version sqs doesnt support celery events. Maybe where is some other way to get information about how many tasks success, how many crashed etc.
My project use Django+Celery+SQS

Answer (score 0):

ClouWatch can give you some monitoring information:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/sqs-metricscollected.html